# How do I convert a string to a double while only using <iostream>, <string>, <cstdlib>, <stdio.h>, and <cassert>?

Tags: c++, string

I'm new to C++ and my teacher gave me a practice program to write (It's just for practice...not homework, and worth no points, so don't worry) and what I have to do is read input from the standard input stream, compare it against some arbitrary strings and then later in the project I have to convert it to a double (thus I cannot read it directly as a double).

So far I can read it in and store it as a string `string input; cin >> input;` however, I don't know how to convert it to a double.  The problem is I'm only allowed to use the following libraries:

```
<iostream>, <string>, <cstdlib>, <stdio.h>, and <cassert>.
```

I've looked at `atof` in `cstdlib` but it only takes in a `char *` not a string.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `std::string` has a method `c_str()` that gives you `char const *`. But are you really allowed to use `atof()`, or are you supposed to figure out how to process the letters in the string to calculate the value of the double? Using `atof()` will hardly teach you anything.

Comment: I'm allowed to use atof() because this is just a small part of a much larger project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
#include <string>

std::string s = "0.5";
double d = std::stod(s);
```

Comment: +1, but let's hope the teacher has a C++11 compiler installed.

Answer (score 2):

> I've looked at atof in cstdlib but it only takes in a `char *` not a `string`.

Calling [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) on a string gives you a `char const *` to its contents, to be passed to C library functions, so you can do

```
 atof(s.c_str())  // where s is an std::string
```

Comment: Is there any way I can tell if the string was a 0 or if it was not a number.  I ask this because it says that atof returns 0 when it cannot parse

Comment: `atof()` sets a global variable `errno` when there's an error. `std::stod()` is easier to use though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <sstream>

double a;
const std::string str = "1.0";
std::istringstream is(str);
is >> a;
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++ string class uses a C character array as its low level storage. You can get that character array back using this

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/